# Django admin inheritance, referencing child model id in parent model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I have a base model and 2 child models inheriting from base model

```html
class Module(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        
class A(Module):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, verbose_name='Title')
  image = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/', null=True)
  
  
class B(Module):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, verbose_name='Title')
  sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, verbose_name='Title')
  image = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/', null=True)
```

This is working fine, Django creates table inside child model table that references to parent.

Now, where I struggle is that there is an additional app with its own model that needs to query related parent model with its all child models. Lets assume this is my app referencing to module class

```html
class Page(models.Model):


    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, null=False, db_index = True)
    modules = models.ManyToManyField('modules.module')
```

By this current setup, Django stores parent model id in child model table, I'm not using django on client side hence in my sql query I'd like to get the child module attached to parent, by having a reference to what child model is referencing to. Please have in mind, Parent is linked to only one model.

I've looked at abstract, proxy models as well as model_utils.managers InheritenceManager but none stored child model information in parent.

How do I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: How are you passing the data to the client?  if JSON, you may want to look into  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer with a "ModelSerializer" you define the shape of data to return to the client

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I think its not what I'm after, regardless of what I use as API, I still think there should be a way to reverse relation by storing child class id in parent record. then it shouldn't matter what I use at API level or client side. FYI, Im using Flask on Lambda

Comment: as it is "ManyToMany", there is an underlying table created to store the relationship (assuming relational DB) You can query it like `Page.objects.prefetch_related('modules')`, but they won't be "attached to the parent", if you convert it to __dict__, for example.   The serializer lets you define how the dictionary representation would look (with modules attached to the page)

Comment: There is no elegant way to reverse this relationship?

Comment: Also, what about related_name=%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related)? @RedTwoon

Comment: with ManyToMany, you should be able to do: `Page.objects.first().modules.all()` and the reverse: `Module.objects.first().pages.all()` (using the default `related_name`s)

Comment: How do I do that in Django admin? or you referring to query? Sorry I'm new to Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship is already defined by the `ManyToManyField`.  Being able to *display* it is perhaps the question you're getting at.

You can reference the "through" model and register it in Admin like so:

```py
from django.contrib import admin


# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects
#
# You can use TabularInline, or StackedInline --- whichever meets your style preferences
#
class PageModuleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Page.modules.through  # the implicit "join table" model

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PageModuleInline,
    ]

class ModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        PageModuleInline,
    ]
```

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models